# Custom drupal view

Tags: drupal, structure

Im kinda new to drupal, and its views. SO can anybody tell me how do i make structure like on picture below
http://d.pr/i/LrYX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to enable the Views UI module as well as Views and its dependencies in order to build views.

You will want to create a content type that represents the 'company'.  Then you will want to give it an image field for the logo, and maybe a link field or a text field if you want it to link back to something.  This is all core in Drupal 7 with the exception of the link field.

When creating the view have it show a grid of fields for the content type you just created.    View creation screen should look something like this.
[image: View configuration]

Add the fields using the AJAX interface on the left and set the grid to show 4 columns in the Settings for the grid format.  This configuration is in the left column under the format header.

The left handle column should look something like this before you start adding fields.
[image]

After that the rest is just CSS.

Comment: thanks for answer, i tried the way you described, but its kinda hard to style it. I couldn't add fields if use anything else then table(e.g html list, grid, etc). Thought maybe there is some module, or something else

Comment: You should be able to add fields in all configurations.  Make sure that the view is set to display fields.  In the format section, Format should be set to grid, and Show should be set to fields.  I updated my answer with an example of the correct configuration.

Comment: That was my mistake. Didnt set view to display fields